# Local notification at specific time

Tags: flutter

I can make a local notification at the app launch but cannot make a scheduled notification at a specific time the code below is my local notification the fires every time I open the application

**local_notification.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

NotificationDetails get _noSound {
  final androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'silent channel id',
    'silent channel name',
    'silent channel description',
    playSound: false,
  );
  final iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails(presentSound: false);

  return NotificationDetails(androidChannelSpecifics, iOSChannelSpecifics);
}

Future showSilentNotification(
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifications, {
      @required String title,
      @required String body,
      int id = 0,
    }) =>
    _showNotification(notifications,
        title: title, body: body, id: id, type: _noSound);

NotificationDetails get _ongoing {
  final androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your channel id',
    'your channel name',
    'your channel description',
    importance: Importance.Max,
    priority: Priority.High,
    ongoing: true,
    autoCancel: false,
  );
  final iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
  return NotificationDetails(androidChannelSpecifics, iOSChannelSpecifics);
}

Future showOngoingNotification(
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifications, {
      @required String title,
      @required String body,
      int id = 0,
    }) =>
    _showNotification(notifications,
        title: title, body: body, id: id, type: _ongoing);

Future _showNotification(
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifications, {
      @required String title,
      @required String body,
      @required NotificationDetails type,
      int id = 0,
    }) =>
    notifications.show(id, title, body, type);
```

**main.dart**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    initNotification();

    showOngoingNotification(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin, title: "fg", body: "dfgdfg");



  }


  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  void initNotification(){
// initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }
  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
    }
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Home()),
    );
  }
  Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    // display a dialog with the notification details, tap ok to go to another page
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => new CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: new Text(title),
        content: new Text(body),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            child: new Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
              await Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                  //builder: (context) => false,
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

My question is how to make scheduled notification at specific time for example at 10:00 pm even when the app is closed ?
I tried many approaches put didn't get what I want even schedule notification not working at all

Comment: Have you already tried notifications.schedule(...) instead of notifications.show(...) in local_notification.dart ?

Comment: anything specific to put in manifest ?

Comment: Yes, give a look at this: https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications#android-integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notifications.schedule(...)` instead of `notifications.show(...)`